# Is it normal to see a limited set of editing tools on Android when revising a question?

Tags: bug, editor

While revising a question from my phone, I was unable to access anything other than "Add picture".

I don't remember this being an issue but I rarely edit from my phone. Can anyone confirm?

I'm using Android 9 with the latest Chrome 86.0.4240.99.

I see the full editing menu when I ask a new question:

[image]

But I only see a menu with the option to add a picture when editing (revising) a previously submitted question:

[image]

Comment: Try using the “full site” linked in the footer of every page. This mobile version is old; use the responsive one. Make sure Responsiveness is enabled (also in the footer).

Comment: Adding the menu options to  the toolbar relies on Javascript. If that is broken for your brand of phone / browser then you get this "bug", depending if your setup is (still) supported. Is that the standard browser on Android that you're using? Please add exact version numbers of both the OS and browser.

Comment: Yes, that's standard on the mobile site view (and FWIW that "Add picture" menu is rather flakey). If you want the full editor you need to use the full site view. (I'm also using an Android phone).

Comment: I've never had any issue with JavaScript that I've been able to see. This is the first oddity I've noticed after having used SE on Android for years.

Comment: I get the full menu when writing a question-- just not when revising it with "edit".

Comment: @Zhro you tapped the "mobile" link in the footer by accident at some point. The new "Ask Question" page simply has no mobile view (because it's new, and mobile theme is going away soon), so you get the full site theme, which include the full toolbar. However, the edit page is old, so it does have mobile view, which has no toolbar. Just tap the "full site" link in the footer and you'll get the full toolbar always.